# Azure AD Invite User

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Trying to invite an user to an external application and receiving this following error when they try to login. Below message says that I need to add external user to the tenant. If that is the issue, how can I add the external user?

*User account 'someaccount@gmail.com' from identity provider 'live.com' does not exist in tenant 'Strockis Dev Directory' and cannot access the application 'Some Guid' in that tenant. The account needs to be added as an external user in the tenant first. Sign out and sign in again with a different Azure Active Directory user account.*

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-create-users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compared with the Azure AD accounts created from your current directory, any other added accounts will be considered as a "Guest", which is the external users. The Guest or External users include two kinds of accounts: Azure AD accounts from another directory, any other social accounts (Microsoft accounts, Goole accounts, Apple accounts, etc).

You can just click "Add a User" on the Azure portal->Azure Active Directory, and then enter the valid UPN(UserPrincipalName) & DisplayName. In your case you can just enter someaccount@gmail.com and after entering it will be recognized as a Guest (External) user automatically like below:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

if you are still using old azure portal, then you will be able to send the bulk B2B invitation , but we can not see the features in new portal, we need to add this one after one.

check this below portal

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-b2b-what-is-azure-ad-b2b